# Azure worker role won't start

Tags: c#, azure, azure-worker-roles

I'm in alpha w/ a product using a backend worker role. The worker role worked about 2 weeks ago but recently I repushed some new stuff and everything seems to be OK except the worker role is not doing it's job (monitoring a message queue)...

I RDP'ed into the worker role instance and found the following event in the machine's event log:

> Session "MA_ETWSESSION_RD00155D47CFD4_QueueWorkerRole_IN_0" failed to
>   start with the following error: 0xC0000035

But otherwise everything is fine (seemingly).

The AppAgentRuntime log even says everything is OK:

> [00001320:00000896, 2013/02/28, 21:05:21.743, 00040000] Role
>   847e925f39f044759cbcdb162c818553.QueueWorkerRole_IN_0 has stabilized.

I have wrapped the main parts of the worker role w/ exception handling trying to grab some mystery error and I have no clue what's doing this...

Comment: Can you add file logging of any exceptions into the Start()/OnRun() methods of the worker role object?  Having a real exception message would be helpful

Comment: You need thorough logging of everything. If you log an exception you need its type and callstack logged, not only the text. You need some actual data to work with, but now all you can is guessing.

Comment: @Igorek: I have wrapped it on the entire run and it's throwing no exception, that's my frustration... When I run this locally the worker role fires every time and when I debug locally and put my azure project in "cloud" mode it runs just fine (but that means that it would only run against the azure message queue, which proves that's deployed correctly)

Comment: @sharptooth: See my comment above... I've wrapped both the run and the initialization of the worker role in try catches before I turned to SO... No exception is getting thrown... I don't understand.

Comment: This means you have to add more logging to find which code is successfully executed last and proceed until you find what doesn't work. You won't find it by guessing.

Comment: Try turning on Azure Infrastructure logging and look into the WADDiagnosticsInfrastructureLogsTable?  there might be something there.  Overall, googling for the 0xC0000035 exception doesn't provide any comfort that this problem can be solved w/o getting Azure support

Answer (score 0):

- Try to re-deploy your service with IntelliTrace enabled.
- Don't just log for your Run method, also trace anything throwing from your OnStart and OnStop method.
- Beware the static members or constructors you may have added to your class - they could fail your object instance to be created even before you get to touch OnStart method.

Other things that can mess up your startup:
* Do you have all the dependencies required to load your assembly deployed to the role instance?
* Have you disabled strong name verification on your dev machine and forgot to sign your assemblies when publishing?